# Error while trying to make an application command discord.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

```
module.exports = {
    prefix: "!apply",
    fn: (msg) => {
        let application = {}
        let filter = (msg) => !msg.author.bot
        let options = {
            max: 1,
            time: 1500
        }
        msg.member.send("Which item do you want to sell")
        .then(dm => {
            return dm.channel.awaitMessages(filter,options)
        })
        .then(collected => {
            application.name = collected.array()[0].content;
            return msg.member.send("Got it, now whats your Discord [ex: Vouchy#0001]")
        })
        .then(dm => {
            return dm.channel.awaitMessages(filter,options)
        })
        .then(collected => {
            application.tag = collected.array()[0].content;
            return msg.member.send('Excellent, Finally, tell us how much you\'re willing to sell it for')
        })
        .then(dm => {
            return dm.channel.awaitMessages(filter,options)
        })
        .then(collected => {
            application.pitch = collect.array()[0].content;
            console.log(application)
        })
    }
}
```

Im trying to create an application in discord, that when a user does !apply it sends them a message and asks them to answer these questions.

but theres an error everytime
[This is an image of the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF5bM.png)

Comment: I couldn't find any docs on `Collection#array`, did you perhaps mean `Collection#toArray`? (`.toArray()`)

Answer (score 0):

The error signifies that `collected.array()[0]` is not defined or invalid. You should add a `console.log(collected)` or `console.log(collected.array()` before you extract `content` from it, to verify that collected/collected.array() is actually defined

Comment: Can you make an example using my code? im pretty new to js so im not sure where to put it

Comment: You have this line: `application.name = collected.array()[0].content`. Add a `console.log(collected)` right before it. Also, as @Elitezen mentioned, `collected.array()` is probably invalid. Try replacing it with `collected.toArray()`